# Reading comments for a FB post with Koala gem with Rails 4

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, koala, koala-gem

I have a rails4 app, from which I can put a wall post to logged in users `facebook` wall. Now what I want to do is read the FB comments for that given post and show then in my application.

I'm using Rails 4 and `koala` gems. Following is my code

`Koala::Facebook::API.new(<user.oauth_token>).get_object("<facebook post id>")` but I'm keep on getting this error.

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}`

And I cannot see any mismatching in the API, strange thing is I remember I'm using the same code about 3-4 weeks back and If I remember correctly it was working fine that time,

it seems like its not an authentication problem because, If I use

`Koala::Facebook::API.new(<user.oauth_token>).get_object("me")` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the `GraphMethodException` `Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api` when the user access token you specified does not have access to the Facebook object you are requesting. Here is a bug report with more specifics:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1418832665047223/

Comment: thanks for the answer, it turns out that user access token was valid , thats why`.get_object("me")` worked, but user was not verified (coz I was using a test user I created... ). Once I verified the user all works fine now..